# Patching fourcc code INZI

Tags: video, patch, video-encoding

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 64 bit to try to capture RGB and Depth images from a Realsense SR300 depth camera.

I have installed the appropriate SDK etc, and the camera is being recognised and producing RGB data. There is also a separate stream producing depth data, but I cannot view this.

When I use the tools that accompany the SR300, namely `realsense-viewer`, I am greeted with an error:

```
RealSense error calling rs2_pipeline_start_with_config(pipe:0xb29f40, config:0xb284e0):
Requested pixel format is not natively supported by the Linux kernel and likely requires a patch for fourcc code INZI!
Alternatively please upgrade to kernel 4.12 or later. Last Error: Inappropriate ioctl for device
```

My kernel version is `4.12.14-041214-generic`.

Googling this problem leads me [to this thread](https://www.spinics.net/lists/linux-media/msg108702.html). Apparently the last post is a patch script that will fix the issue, but I have no idea what to do with it.

Any guidance I could get on resolving this issue would be appreciated

Comment: Funny, I had exactly the same error but with 4.10 kernel. I have updated to 4.12.14-041214 and now I am able to execute realsense-viewer with SR300 camera. Firmware version of the camera: 3.21.0.0

Comment: Thanks for letting me know, I've tried 4 different kernels now, and still no luck. My camera firmware version is `3.15.0.0` so maybe that's the problem

Comment: You can try [this tool](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/25044/Intel-RealSense-Depth-Camera-Manager) for windows that upgrade firmware easily when it starts